# Autoloading functions best practices

Tags: php, function, static-libraries, autoload

When working on a PHP project that takes advantage of the OOP paradigm with PHP's `__autoload()` function, which of the following is considered the best practice for managing stand-alone functions:

(*Examples provided are simplified for the sake of brevity*)

> **tl;dr**: How is stand-alone function loading commonly handled:
>
> - pseudo-autoloading (via `__callStatic` magic for example) [**Option 1**]
> - abstract helper class grouped static methods [**Option 2**]
> - an alternative

*Also note, I've posted a related question regarding a parameter/reference issue with **option 1**, which can be found here: [__callStatic(), call_user_func_array(), references, and PHP 5.3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602616/callstatic-call-user-func-array-references-and-php-5-3-1)*

**Given in `index.php`:**

```
function __autoload($class){
    require $class . '.class.php';
}
```

**Option 1; An abstract `Core` class (or `Library`, or whatever) that "autoloads" functions:**

```
## Core.class.php
abstract class Core{
    public static function __callStatic($function, $arguments){
        if(!function_exists($function)){
            require $function . '.function.php';
        }
        return call_user_func_array($function, $arguments);
    }
}

## SayHello.function.php
function sayHello(){
    echo 'Hello';
}

## SayGoodbye.function.php
function sayGoodbye(){
    echo 'Goodbye';
}

## index.php
Core::sayHello();   // Hello
Core::sayGoodbye(); // Goodbye
```

**Option 2; Grouping related functions into abstract "helper" classes to be called statically:**

```
## SayStuff.class.php
abstract class SayStuff{
    public static function sayHello(){
        echo 'Hello';
    }
    public static function sayGoodbye(){
        echo 'Goodbye';
    }
}

## index.php
SayStuff::sayHello();   // Hello
SayStuff::sayGoodbye(); // Goodbye
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use 'Option 1' mostly because it uses call_user_func* which will be slower that calling function directly.

If you only need some helper functions that doesn't really tie together, then I would, probably, include a file helpers.php which would just have a list of all my helper functions which are not encapsulated in static class since encapsulation doesn't really achieve anything in this case. Most of the times helper functions will be used for every request so including this file on every request won't cause any harm...

Comment: **Thanks rATRIJS;** I was thinking along those lines too, this could bottleneck heavily with recursive functions. Over time, I've written lots of functions that essentially extend the PHP core functionality, and while some may be used in a given project, some won't. Dividing them into logical groups (classes) is difficult, due to the generality of some, however that is an option I'm still considering. Loading them all every time as a single massive library isn't optimal (I don't think) due to the sheer size it will become when I finish consolidating my library.

Comment: Another issue I've noticed with "option 1" is functions with arguments that get passed by reference, simply don't work of course. Had forgotten about that caveat.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see a precise question here, but since the title contains "best practices", here's a piece of advice that I've recently discovered:

It [seems to be preferable to use PHP's **SPL autoload functions** instead of **__autoload()**](http://dissectionbydavid.wordpress.com/2010/11/03/php-spl-autoload-vs-__autoload/) (nice example on "Dissection by David" blog).

Quoting the linked blog post:

> The biggest benefits of using the SPL
>   version (that I can see to-date) are:
>
> - more than one function can be used/registered — functions are
>     chained together and used sequentially
>     up to the point of one function
>     loading the class file. + functions can be unregistered on-the-fly, too.
> - there is some nice error handling that can be implemented (see
>     example 3), although some hat
>     try/catch so this may not fit your
>     coding style.
> - using a different extension (i.e. not .php or .php.inc or .inc) if
>     you so choose with
>     spl_autoload_extensions()
> - makes sure that ‘my’ autoloading class is not overwritten!  If
>     `__autoload()` is run later, my `spl_autoload_register()`’ed functions
>     will not be replaced.

Comment: In addition to this, it may be a good idea to use a PSR-0 compliant autoloader. For more info, see http://groups.google.com/group/php-standards/web/psr-0-final-proposal

Comment: **Thanks Frosty Z;** I appreciate the suggestion of `SPL` over non-`SPL` autoloading. I'll certainly begin implementing it in future projects, in lieu of the core provided `__autoload`. I'll add a **tl;dr** to my question for summation.