# __callStatic(), call_user_func_array(), references, and PHP 5.3.1

Tags: php, pass-by-reference, magic-methods, dynamic-function

I've been reading around on SO, and elsewhere, however I can't seem to find anything conclusive.

Is there any way to effectively carry references through this call stack, resulting in the desired functionality as described in the example below? While the example doesn't try to solve it, it certainly illustrates the problem:

```
class TestClass{
    // surely __call would result similarly
    public static function __callStatic($function, $arguments){
        return call_user_func_array($function, $arguments);
    }
}

// note argument by reference
function testFunction(&$arg){
    $arg .= 'bar';
}

$test = 'foo';
TestClass::testFunction($test);

// expecting: 'foobar'
// getting:   'foo' and a warning about the reference
echo $test;
```

---

### For the sake of inspiring a potential resolution, I'm going to add summary details here:

Focusing on only `call_user_func_array()`, we can determine that (*at least with PHP 5.3.1*) you cannot implicitly pass arguments by reference:

```
function testFunction(&$arg){
    $arg .= 'bar';
}

$test = 'foo';
call_user_func_array('testFunction', array($test));
var_dump($test);
// string(3) "foo" and a warning about the non-reference parameter
```

By explicitly passing the array element `$test` as a reference, we can alleviate this:

```
call_user_func_array('testFunction', array(&$test));
var_dump($test);
// string(6) "foobar"
```

When we introduce the class with `__callStatic()`, an explicit call-time parameter by reference seems to carry through as I expected, but deprecation warnings are issued (in my IDE):

```
class TestClass{
    public static function __callStatic($function, $arguments){
        return call_user_func_array($function, $arguments);
    }
}

function testFunction(&$arg){
    $arg .= 'bar';
}

$test = 'foo';
TestClass::testFunction(&$test);
var_dump($test);
// string(6) "foobar"
```

Omission of the reference operator in `TestClass::testFunction()` results in `$test` being passed by value to `__callStatic()`, and of course is passed by value as an array element to `testFunction()` via `call_user_func_array()`. This results in a warning, since `testFunction()` expects a reference.

Hacking around, some additional details have surfaced. The `__callStatic()` definition, if written to return by reference (`public static function &__callStatic()`) has no visible effect. Furthermore, recasting the elements of the `$arguments` array in `__callStatic()` as references we can see that `call_user_func_array()` works somewhat as expected:

```
class TestClass{
    public static function __callStatic($function, $arguments){
        foreach($arguments as &$arg){}
        call_user_func_array($function, $arguments);
        var_dump($arguments);
        // array(1) {
        //   [0]=>
        //   &string(6) "foobar"
        // }
    }
}

function testFunction(&$arg){
    $arg .= 'bar';
}

$test = 'foo';
TestClass::testFunction($test);
var_dump($test);
// string(3) "foo"
```

These results are expected, as `$test` is no longer passed by reference, the change is not passed back into it's scope. However, this confirms that `call_user_func_array()` is in fact working as expected, and that the issue is certainly confined to the calling magic.

**Upon further reading, it appears it may be a "bug" in PHP's handling of user functions, and the `__call()`/`__callStatic()` magic. I've perused the bug database for existing or related issues, and had found one, but haven't been able to locate it again. I'm considering issuing another report, or a request for the existing report to be reopened.**

Comment: It appears that the issue is more to do with the `__call()` magic than `call_user_func_array()`... Furthermore, it doesn't seem there's a particularly clean workaround. Still, any thoughts are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a fun one.

```
TestClass::testFunction(&$string);
```

This works, but it also throws a call-time-pass-by-reference warning.

The main issue is that `__callStatic`'s second argument comes in by value.  It's creating a *copy* of the data, unless that data is *already* a reference.

We can duplicate the calling error thusly:

```
call_user_func_array('testFunction', array( $string ));
// PHP Warning:  Parameter 1 to testFunction() expected to be a reference, value given

call_user_func_array('testFunction', array( &$string ));
echo $string;
// 'helloworld'
```

I tried to modify the `__callStatic` method to copy the array deeply by reference, but that didn't work either.

I'm pretty sure that the immediate copy caused by `__callStatic` is going to be a killer here, and that you won't be able to do this without enough hoop jumping to make it a bit sticker, syntax-wise.

Comment: **Thanks Charles;** Yea, I figured that the call magic would be the problem. I've noticed it's popped up in the PHP bugfix requests, yet has not been patched (from what I've found at least) Explicitly passing the arguments by reference of course throws a warning as you've noted, and unfortunately that wouldn't be satisfactory solution anyways. What sort of hoop jumping did you have in mind, no matter how insane?

Comment: Unfortunately the only thing I can come up with would be not using `__callStatic` at all, which probably isn't going to help you much here.  Can you tell us more about what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Well, it's become an academic trial now, but the purpose initially comes from this question I posted earlier; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5600883/autoloading-functions-best-practices The first proposed option to handle autoloading unclassed function libraries takes advantage of `__callStatic`. Though it may be beneficial for optimization purposes to go a different route, I'd still like to solve this, as it (to me at least) seems like a very clean solution.

Comment: Hm, interesting idea, though I'm not sure if PHP is the right language to pull off that kind of magic.  If this was Perl or Ruby, I'm sure it could be done...

Comment: Yea, I was also hoping I could take advantage of this functionality for other purposes. The autoloading classless function libraries was a start, but I was rolling around some other ideas for a lightweight educational MVC framework I'm developing, and this would have been an asset. I'll keep hunting. Thanks again **Charles**, if any other ideas come to mind, I'd be happy to hear them.

Answer (score 2):

I'm answering this myself with a step-by-step reproduction of the issue, which demonstrates that it is likely not possible to achieve the desired functionality.

Our test function is fairly straightforward, and is as follows:

```
function testFunction(&$argument)
{
    $argument++;
}
```

If we call the function directly, it, of course, behaves as expected:

```
$value = 1;
testFunction($value);
var_dump($value); // int(2)
```

If we call the function using `call_user_func_array`:

```
call_user_func_array('testFunction', [$value]);
var_dump($value); // int(1)
```

The value remains at `1`, because `$value` was not passed by reference. We can force this:

```
call_user_func_array('testFunction', [&$value]);
var_dump($value); // int(2)
```

Which again works as calling the function directly.

Now, we introduce the class, using `__callStatic`:

```
class TestClass
{
    public static function __callStatic($name, $argumentArray)
    {
        return call_user_func_array($name, $argumentArray);
    }
}
```

If we call the function by forwarding it through `__callStatic`:

```
TestClass::testFunction($value);
var_dump($value); // int(1)
```

The value remains at `1`, *and* we also get a warning:

> `Warning: Parameter 1 to testFunction() expected to be a reference, value given`

Which verifies that `$argumentArray` passed into `__callStatic` does not contain references. That makes perfect sense, as PHP doesn't know the arguments are intended to be accepted by reference in `__callStatic`, nor that we are forwarding the arguments on.

If we change `__callStatic` to accept the array by reference, in an attempt to force the desired behaviour:

```
public static function __callStatic($name, &$argumentArray)
{
    return call_user_func_array($name, $argumentArray);
}
```

Uh oh! Spaghetti-O's!

> `Fatal error: Method TestClass::__callstatic() cannot take arguments by reference`

Can't do that; besides, that's [supported by the documentation anyway](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php):

> **Note:**
>   None of the arguments of these magic methods can be passed by reference.

Despite not being able to declare `__callStatic` to accept by reference, if we use `call_user_func_array` (*which would be rather awkward and self-defeating in practice*) to forward references through `__callStatic`:

```
call_user_func_array(['TestClass', 'testFunction'], [&$value]);
var_dump($value); // int(2)
```

It once again works.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, after more than hour of blowing my mind, I'm still not sure but...

```
mixed call_user_func_array ( callback $function , array $param_arr )
```

If we use simple logic (in this situation) when class calls function `call_user_func_array()` it uses static strings as parameters (passed by magic method `__callStatic()`), so parameter 2 is a string in eyes of `call_user_func_array()` function and that parameter is also parameter 1 for function `testFunction()`. It's simply string not a pointer to variable, and that probably is a reason for message like:

```
Warning: Parameter 1 to testFunction() expected to be a reference, value given in ... on line ...
```

In other words, it just can't assign value back to variable that doesn't exist but still, testFunction() expects parameter to be a reference and throws warning because it's not.

You can test it out of class like:

```
function testFunction(&$arg){
    $arg .= 'world';
  }

$string = 'hello';
call_user_func_array('testFunction', array($string));
echo $string;
```

**It throws same Warning!** So problem is not with class, problem is this function.

This function obviously passes function parameters as static data without pointing to variables and functions it calls just can not handle referenced arguments.

Comment: **Thanks Wh1T3h4Ck5;** We've sifted it down to being an issue of calling magic. `__call()`/`__callStatic()` don't carry a reference into their defined bodies via the argument array, at least not by any conventional means. The function definition for the call magic (or any magic function as per docs) furthermore does not permit passing the arguments by reference.

Answer (score 0):

After years I had a moment of serendipity:

```
class TestClass{
    public static function __callStatic($functionName, $arguments) {
        $arguments[0]->{'ioParameter'} = 'two';
    }
}
$objectWrapper = new StdClass();
$objectWrapper->{'ioParameter'} = 'one';
TestClass::testFunction($objectWrapper);
var_dump($objectWrapper); 
// outputs: object(stdClass)#3 (1) { ["ioParameter"]=> string(3) "two" }
```

(tested on php 5.5)

This workaround is clean and viable if you control the interfaces.

It works by wrapping arguments in an object, which by language definition, is always passed around "by reference".

It allows for passing writable (reference) parameters even using __callStatic (and possibly __call).