# Return null by reference via __get()

Tags: php, null, reference, magic-methods

Quick specs:

```
PHP 5.3
error_reporting(-1) // the highest
```

I'm using the `__get()` by reference trick to magically access arbitrarily deep array elements in an object.

Quick example:

```
public function &__get($key){
    return isset($this->_data[$key])
        ? $this->_data[$key]
        : null;
}
```

This doesn't work as when the `$key` isn't set, it tries to return `null` by reference, which of course throws *`Only variable references should be returned by reference ...`* I tried modifying it as follows:

```
public function &__get($key){
    $null = null;
    return isset($this->_data[$key])
        ? $this->_data[$key]
        : $null;
}
```

Still doesn't work though, I'm assuming that setting `$null` to `null` essentially `unset()`s it.

What can I do? Thanks!

---

Just figured I'd promote this question, as it's somewhat relevant (*PHP magic and references*); [__callStatic(), call_user_func_array(), references, and PHP 5.3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602616/callstatic-call-user-func-array-references-and-php-5-3-1). I've yet to find an answer ...besides modifying the PHP core.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `null`, but rather the ternary operator:

Rewriting it with an `if/else` won't throw the notice:

```
public function &__get($key)
{
    $null = null;
    if (isset($this->_data[$key])) {
        return $this->_data[$key];
    } else {
        return $null;
    }
}
```

Ternary operators cannot result in references. They can only return **values**.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks **webbiedave**; why is it the ternary operator causes the error?

Comment: Awesome info in the edit there **webbiedave**; did not know that about ternary operators. Will certainly commit that to memory. Wish I could **+2**.

Comment: +1 Nice answer. I didn't know about this ternary operator behaviour.

Comment: You don't need the else ;)

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem, but I ended up realizing that I shouldn't return null when the key wasn't found, but **throw an exception** (because I was accessing an unknown attribute after all).

But maybe that's not what you want to do, I just wanted to share that.

Comment: Thanks **Matthieu**; I considered that, however I think returning `null` will be my best bet under the circumstances.

Answer (score 4):

Why return `null` explicitly? If `$key` doesn't exist in `$this->_data` it's going to return `NULL` anyway?

I recommend using the following and adjust your logic on the other end. You're probably already checking for `null` now. You could change it to `empty()` or some other variant. Or use exceptions as suggested by **Matthieu**.

```
public function &__get($key){
    return $this->_data[$key];
}
```

Comment: By golly! The simplest answer obscured by overusing `isset` as per "best practices". Thanks **Jason McCreary**!

Comment: I'm not advocating the disuse of `isset()`. But considering your logic and the dynamic nature of PHP, this accomplishes the same thing. It may report a `Notice` though for keys that do not exist. You should check out **webbiedave's** answer if this bothers you.

Comment: I didn't receive any notices though. Is `error_reporting(-1)` excluding something? I read it covers all reporting levels, even future safe.

Comment: It may not due to the pass by reference. However, you should pass `error_reporting()` the appropriate flags. Not the explicit value - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: On the contrary; the tip provided on that page explains `-1` is a future safe full reporting level. I would think that would be best (*at least for cross-platform development environments*)

Comment: Fair enough. I didn't scroll down to see that as the parameter description didn't mention `-1`. Good to know. Thanks.

Comment: And thank you. I'm going with your answer for it's brevity, though SO should introduce two types of "correct answers"; one that answers the question explicitly (**webbiedave**'s) and one that provides an equally correct, optimized alternative (**yours**)

Comment: In the end it's what you decide is the answer for you. That's why there's the checkmark and upvotes. I gave **webbiedave** credit with a +1.